# pyspark.sql.functions - count to consider null values:

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to get the `pyspark.sql.functions.count()` function or the `pyspark.sql.functions.count_distinct()` function to consider `null` values when counting the number of distinct elements within a column.

Let me give the following reproducible example, for which I need to create a dataset:

```
# Dataframe Creation 
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"arun","engineering",20000),\
                            (2,"manoj","finance",25000),\
                            (3,None,"accounts",None),\
                            (4,"vikram",None,None)],\
                           ["id","name","dept","salary"])
```

The resulting dataframe looks as follows:

```
+---+------+-----------+------+
| id|  name|       dept|salary|
+---+------+-----------+------+
|  1|  arun|engineering| 20000|
|  2| manoj|    finance| 25000|
|  3|  null|   accounts|  null|
|  4|vikram|       null|  null|
+---+------+-----------+------+
```

Now if I run the following code to count the number of distinct values in each column:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df.agg(func.count("id").alias("n_ids"),\
       func.count("name").alias("n_names"),\
       func.count("dept"),\
       func.count("salary"))\
  .show()
```

I get the following output:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+-------------+
|n_ids|n_names|count(dept)|count(salary)|
+-----+-------+-----------+-------------+
|    4|      3|          3|            2|
+-----+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

I get the same output if I substitute `func.count()` for `func.count_distinct()` in the above snippet.

From my research, this seems to be related to the fact that `count_distinct()` works in the same way as [HIVE `count(DISTINCT expr[, expr])`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

> count(DISTINCT expr[, expr]) - Returns the number of rows for which
> the supplied expression(s) are unique and non-NULL.

I would like the `null` values to be considered in the count of distinct values, resulting in the following output:

```
+-----+-------+-----------+-------------+
|n_ids|n_names|count(dept)|count(salary)|
+-----+-------+-----------+-------------+
|    4|      4|          4|            3|
+-----+-------+-----------+-------------+
```

This is in fact the output we get if we use the DataFrame API functions `distinct()` and `count()` applied to one column, because `distinct()` coniders null values by default.

```
df.select("salary").distinct().count() # Returns 3, taking the null value into account.
```

**QUESTION**:

How can I use the `pyspark.sql.functions.count()` or `pyspark.sql.functions.count_distinct()` to consider the `null` values when determining the number of distinct records in a column?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function of your own.
basically, count the distinct values and then count the non-null rows. if the non-null rows are not equal to the number of rows in the dataframe it means at least one row is null, in this case add +1 for the null value(s) in the column.

```
def count_distinct_with_nulls(c):
    distinct_values = func.count_distinct(c)
    null_rows = func.sum(func.when(func.col(c).isNull(), 1).otherwise(0))

    return func.when(
        null_rows == 0,
        distinct_values
    ).otherwise(distinct_values + 1)
```

Running it in a `select` or `agg` clause will work just fine.

```
df.select(*[count_distinct_with_nulls(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()

+---+----+----+------+
| id|name|dept|salary|
+---+----+----+------+
|  4|   4|   4|     3|
+---+----+----+------+
```

An additional solution, not sure if it's best practice but you can fill all na columns with values and run the normal count_distinct function.

e.g: `df.fillna(-1).fillna("-1")` will fill -1 in numeric columns and "-1" in string columns.

Comment: Is there any difference between using this function and using directly `df.count()`?

I would like to be able to include this function within a multiple aggregation statement such as `df.agg` in my example. Does that work?

Comment: edited my answer with a function you can plug and play in agg, select or groupBy(...).agg  :)

Comment: Thank you, have not had time to test it yet. Will do later today.